# How to pass header in Azure endpoint..?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-api-apps, azure-api-management, azure-hub

I am using `Azure API` , URL getting below error please help on this issue. please share codesnip, how to change in `web.config` and endpoints.

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'AzureApiManagementKey
>   realm="https:/azure.azure-api.net/MethodName",name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",type="header"'.

Comment: can you add more details on what you are trying to do what is the client application and so on.

Comment: I am using WSDL provided by API Management and facing this issue while invoking method inside that services.

Comment: What are you doing with the WSDL provided by API Management?  How was that API created in APIM?  Via WSDL?  Where is the error you are receiving coming from?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question still, my answer would help someone faces the same issue.

The solution is to create a custom endpoint behavior where you add a custom message handler to the binding parameters.

In the custom message handler, please add your request headers. After this, use any of the binding technique (like basichttpsbinding or NetHttpsBinding) with security mode as "Transport" and MessageEncoding as "Text" for creating soap client object. Add custom endpoint behavior to the soap client.

```
public class CustomEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        bindingParameters.Add(new Func<HttpClientHandler, HttpMessageHandler>(x =>
        {
            return new CustomMessageHandler(x);
        }));
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime) { }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) { }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) { }
}

public class CustomMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public CustomMessageHandler(HttpClientHandler handler)
    {
        InnerHandler = handler;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Add("xxxx", "abcde");
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

The console app to consume the service.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
        var client = GetSOAPClient();

        try
        {
            var result = await client.MyOperation().ConfigureAwait(false);
            if(result.Body != null && result.Body.status == "Success")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result.Body.myValue);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex?.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static MyServiceClient GetSOAPClient()
    {
        NetHttpsBinding binding = new NetHttpsBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.MessageEncoding = NetHttpMessageEncoding.Text;
        EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://myazureurl"));

        var client = new MyServiceClient(binding, ea);
        client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CustomEndpointBehavior());

        return client;
    }
}
```

Comment: The above solution is on the assumption that the APIM registration is done without any other authentication mechanism. If your SOAP pass through service expects any authentication, you can add that with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is complaining that your Subscription key is wrong.  If you check the response body, it will give you a readable message of what the real problem is.  Double check you are entering the correct subscription key for your Azure API access.

You get your subscription key from the Developer Portal under your profile menu. You can see an example of the subscription key being used in this article under the section "Call an operation from the developer portal": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-get-started

Also, the 'The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.' part of the message is a red herring and a separate problem with how responses work.